# What's the difference between Link and Path in PDDL?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, planning, pddl

In the driverlog domain in PDDL we have specified links and paths.

```
(define (domain driverlog)
  (:requirements :typing) 
  (:types         location locatable - object
        driver truck obj - locatable
  )
  (:predicates 
        (at ?obj - locatable ?loc - location)
        (in ?obj1 - obj ?obj - truck)
        (driving ?d - driver ?v - truck)
        (link ?x ?y - location) (path ?x ?y - location)
        (empty ?v - truck)
 )
```

And the way that it's defined in the problem is:

```
(define (problem DLOG-2-2-2)
    (:domain driverlog)
    (:objects
    driver1 - driver
    driver2 - driver
    truck1 - truck
    truck2 - truck
    package1 - obj
    package2 - obj
    s0 - location
    s1 - location
    s2 - location
    p1-0 - location
    p1-2 - location
    )
    (:init
    (at driver1 s2)
    (at driver2 s2)
    (at truck1 s0)
    (empty truck1)
    (at truck2 s0)
    (empty truck2)
    (at package1 s0)
    (at package2 s0)
    (path s1 p1-0)
    (path p1-0 s1)
    (path s0 p1-0)
    (path p1-0 s0)
    (path s1 p1-2)
    (path p1-2 s1)
    (path s2 p1-2)
    (path p1-2 s2)
    (link s0 s1)
    (link s1 s0)
    (link s0 s2)
    (link s2 s0)
    (link s2 s1)
    (link s1 s2)
    )
```

What's the difference between paths and links? I've tried to create a similar problem but omitting the path and I keep getting Unsolvable Problem. How can I properly define a path?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are user-defined predicates:

```
(define (domain driverlog)
  ...
  (:predicates 
        ...
        (link ?x ?y - location) (path ?x ?y - location)
        ...
  )
 )
```

so their semantics can be deduced by inspecting the corresponding model.

Both `link` and `path` are **binary predicates** that put in relation **two locations**, presumably when it's possible to move from one place to the other. This connection is unidirectional.

I read, from the [source code](https://github.com/raznis/dist-selfish-fd/blob/master/benchmarks/driverlog/domain.pddl), that the following actions are defined:

```
(:action DRIVE-TRUCK
  :parameters
   (?truck
    ?loc-from
    ?loc-to
    ?driver)
  :precondition
   (and (TRUCK ?truck) (LOCATION ?loc-from) (LOCATION ?loc-to) (DRIVER ?driver) 
   (at ?truck ?loc-from)
   (driving ?driver ?truck) (link ?loc-from ?loc-to))
  :effect
   (and (not (at ?truck ?loc-from)) (at ?truck ?loc-to)))

(:action WALK
  :parameters
   (?driver
    ?loc-from
    ?loc-to)
  :precondition
   (and (DRIVER ?driver) (LOCATION ?loc-from) (LOCATION ?loc-to)
    (at ?driver ?loc-from) (path ?loc-from ?loc-to))
  :effect
   (and (not (at ?driver ?loc-from)) (at ?driver ?loc-to)))
```

So it seems that two locations have a **link** if it is possible to `DRIVE-TRUCK` from one place to the other, and two locations have a **path** if it is possible to `WALK` from one place to the other.

There is really nothing else to say about it.

The reason why you keep getting `UNSAT` is because you *placed the drivers and the trucks in two different locations*:

```
(at driver1 s2)
(at driver2 s2)
(at truck1 s0)
(at truck2 s0)
```

Since the only connection among `s0` and `s2` is a **link**, the drivers cannot possibly reach the truck (and vice-versa). This is because a precondition of `DRIVE-TRUCK` is `(driving ?driver ?truck)`, which is only set by  `BOARD-TRUCK` if the driver is in the same location of the truck.

You can solve this issue by creating a path among `s0` and `s2`. However, this seems to be against the naming convention of the model, which interconnects `sX` using links only. A better solution is to change the initial state and put a truck in the same location of each driver, or at least in a location that is reachable by the `WALK` action.